# Adding 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' eventListeners on something with getElementByTagName() only applying event to last item

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

everyone. I'm currently having an issue with a 15 piece slide puzzle I am trying to make. The criteria is that when I mouse over a piece in my slide puzzle, it is supposed to set the border on that piece as red, and when I move my mouse off of it the border should go back to black. The problem is that the mouseover and mouseout events only seem to work on the last item passed through the for loop, and I'm having trouble working out a solution.

I've tried a lot of different ways, including writing the eventListeners with other combinations of code, but haven't gotten a successful result. This is actually the closest I've gotten.

Here is the specific code in question:

```
function movePiece(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){

        var item = elements.item(i);

        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
            item.style.border = "5px solid red";
        },false);

        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
            console.log(item);
            item.style.border = "5px solid black";
        },false);
    }
}
```

And the HTML that goes along with it(I would like to note that this is a class asignment, so unfortunately changing this HTML is not allowed):

```html
        <div id="puzzlearea">
            <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
            <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
        </div>
```

And here is some of the code that shows how I. create the puzzle and then shuffle it once the shuffle button has been pressed:

```js
window.onload = onPageLoad;

/*
 * Loads the page with the initial puzzle, and operates all game logic.
 */
function onPageLoad() {
  createPuzzle();
  document.getElementById("shufflebutton").onclick = makeShuffle;
}

function playGame() {
    movePiece();
}

/*
 * Creates the initial puzzle. We go through each div in the puzzlearea
 * and set the position of the tile, as well as the image. This puzzle is
 * created in the correct, or completed, order.
 */
function createPuzzle() {
  var puzzlePiece = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(let i = 0; i < puzzlePiece.length; i++) {
    var item =  puzzlePiece.item(i);
    item.style.left = getLeftPosition(i);
    item.style.top = getTopPosition(i);
    item.style.backgroundPosition = getBackgroundPosition(i);
  }
}

/*
 * Shuffles the puzzle board. We go through each div in the puzzlearea
 * and set the position of the tile, as well as the image, based on the
 * shuffled order.
 */
function makeShuffle() {
  var puzzlePiece = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").getElementsByTagName('div');
  // Array of 0-14 in random order.
  var order = shuffleBoard();
  for(let i = 0; i < puzzlePiece.length; i++) {
    var loc = order[i];
    var item =  puzzlePiece.item(i);
    item.style.position = "absolute";
    item.style.left = getLeftPosition(loc);
    item.style.top = getTopPosition(loc);
    item.style.backgroundPosition = getBackgroundPosition(i);
  }
    playGame();
}
```

And, if needed, a bit of the relevant CSS:

```css
#puzzlearea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#puzzlearea div {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  float: left;
  cursor: default;
}
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: what not just use CSS :hover

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain and use CSS: `#puzzlearea > div {border:5px solid black;} #puzzlearea > div:hover {border:5px solid red;}`

Comment: If you are allowed to add some [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to your code than you can use of a [Pseudo-class](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) named [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript events to do this at all, just use a new CSS selector

```css
#puzzlearea div:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

here's a demo with most of your code

```css
#puzzlearea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#puzzlearea div {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  float: left;
  cursor: default;
}

#puzzlearea div:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

#puzzlearea div.state-1:hover {
  border-color: green;
}

#puzzlearea div.state-2:hover {
  border-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="puzzlearea">
    <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
    <div class="state-1">1</div>  <div class="state-2">2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
    <div class="state-1">5</div>  <div class="state-2">6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, and I'm sorry that I didn't specify this, but the next step I'm going to have to do is only change the border color of a piece if a certain condition is met. Is there a simpler way to incorporate this into that? Or are we talking about something more in depth?

Essentially, if a piece can be moved into the empty slot of the slide puzzle, then it needs to change to a red border on a hover.

Comment: You could add CSS classes for the different conditions, and then have CSS rules that override the previous hover states.  I've updated the code in my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a hover selector to your css

```
border: 5px solid black;

:hover {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, you can achieve this easily with CSS. But as this is only a step within a larger plan of action, your function should work by changing `item.style.border` to `e.target.style.border`.

This is because at the time the event listener is applied, the loop has finished, and the eventHandler functions (attached to each element) reffers to `item` as the last item in the `for loop`.

```
function movePiece(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
            e.target.style.border = "5px solid red";
        },false);

        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
            console.log(e.target);
            e.target.style.border = "5px solid black";
        },false);
    }
};
```

The same result could be used with `forEach()` insead of the `for loop`, or by using `let` instead of `var` within the loop itself, but for a beginner it would be better to simply create self-contained eventHandlers.

I would recommend googling away 'for loop eventlistener' as there are a lot of resources available on the matter.